# django 4.0 - can't login with registered user

Tags: python, django

Here is the django shell output:

```
>>> for user in User.objects.all():
...     print(user.username, user.password, len(user.password))
... 
ll_admin pbkdf2_sha256$320000$zm6RcAswZJR6B7uXaCVNVd$hRs9nZKWBPpfemhC2yL16XE0wLCRa4Z0dlbUATywleA= 88
ams 1243 4
who 1243 4
whos 1243 4
whosa 1243 4
maksd 1243 4
1243 1243 4
abcde 12345 5
ids 1243 4
amsfd 1234567 7
cancal 1111 4
>>>
```

Here is the login view code:

```py
    def user_login(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('homepage:index'))
            else:
                message = "User doesn't exist or password is incorrect." + "( " + username + ", " + password + " )"
        else:
            message = ''
        form = UserForm()
        context = {"form": form, "message": message}
        return render(request, 'users/login.html', context)
```

I sign in with ams, 1243 for example, it shows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Rq3.jpg

The password is set with register function like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtGGz.jpg . Here is the register view code:

```py
def user_register(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # display a blank form
        form = UserForm()
    else:
        form = UserForm(data = request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save() # the user is saved to database
            login(request, new_user) # login, not user_login in views.py
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('homepage:index'))
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

I checked the password and username and they match. So kind of feel confused right now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How did you set these passwords?

Comment: i set these passwords with a register function. i'll add the register view code.

Comment: Your register function stores the password in plain text. That is very insecure. You should read this part of the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/

Comment: The weird part is: i can login with ll_admin and newly created account( after i registered a a new account, it will automatically login. But if i logout and login again, it shows no such user). Is it because of the plain text password?

Comment: Yes, the password for the admin account is set up correctly, but the others are not.